# React + Redux share actions between modules/domains

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Imagine you have an application with 2 modules (split up in the ducks way).
One is the eagerly loaded `Notification` module, which is used to display notifications when something succeeds or fails. 
The other is a `Calculation` which makes some calculation

```
- Notification
    - components
    - actions
    - ...
    - index.js
- Calculation
    - components
    - actions
    - ...
    - index.js
```

In a lot of architecture articles they recommend that you should then export the action creators for each module through an `index.js` file, that sort of functions as the public API of your module. 
For example, if I wanted to expose the a `success` action creator of my `Notification` module, then I'd export it from the `index.js` file in that module. Now my other modules can import these action creators.

I like this idea of a public facing API in your module.
What I find troublesome with that way of working is that you then very tightly couple the module to the redux library. Because if I'd switch to a new `Notification` module, then this module would have to expose action creators too, which is tied to redux.

Is my concern valid? If so, can you suggest a better (but still idiomatic) solution?

What I would do in **Angular** is the following:
I'd expose from the `Notification` module a singleton service that acts as the  public facing API of this module. If any other module (eg. `Calculation`) needed to use a feature in the `Notification` module they could inject the service using dependency injection and call `notificationService.addNotification('message')`. In that singleton service I would then call the `dispatch` method on my `store`.

The `Calculation` module does not need to know whether the `NotificationModule` uses a store or not. And I could easily switch around the `Notification` module, as long as a public facing singleton service still exposed the `addNotification` method. By inverting the dependencies, I don't need to go change every module that uses the `Notification` module.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Hey, check my Alert component: https://github.com/cyruzin/react-redux-typescript/blob/master/src/redux/ducks/alert.ts

Comment: Hi @CyroDubeux, your `Alert` component has exactly the issue I'm talking about. When your `Authentication` component wants to send an alert, it has to `dispatch` the `sendAlert` action. But this implies that the `Alert` component is using redux, because you use dispatch. What if you decided to replace the `Alert` component with a component that doesn't use redux?

Comment: Indeed. This one is for global alerts, perhaps another one for simple alerts?

Comment: I don't think you've understood my question. I'm trying to decouple the `Notification` module (in your case `Alert` module) as much as possible. Even for global alerts, I would love to just call a `sendAlert` function from within my other modules without having to `dispatch` it (because else there is a coupling with both the `Notifications` module and with the `redux` library). Then if that `sendAlert` function is called, the `Notification` module should handle the dispatching itself.

Comment: Are you using different store for Notification module and Calculation module?

Comment: This is a hypothetical scenario. But I'd say we should go from the assumption that I'm using the same store for both those modules, but have different reducers. As recommended by the redux library: https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself

Answer (score 3):

What about using `connect` function? This way your component

1. Can be user without Redux at all
2. `dispatch` and other similar redux staff will be hidden behind `connect`

Here is example

```
export const MyComponent = ({ alertState, notificationsArray, SetAlert, AddNotification }) => {
  return <div>
    Alert state: {alertState.toString()}
    <button onClick={() => SetAlert(!alertState)}>Toggle alert</button>
    <div>
      Notifications: {notificationsArray.map(n => `${n}, `)}
      <button onClick={() => AddNotification()}>Add notification</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}

export default connect(state => ({ alertState: state.alert.alertState, notificationsArray: state.notifications.notificationsArray }), {...Alerts.actionCreators, ...notification.actionsCreators})(MyComponent)
```

Note, that inside `MyComponent` there is no `dispatch`. So you can use `MyComponent` without Redux by doing

```
// Another file
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent.js'

export const App = () => {
  return <MyComponent alertState={true} SetAlert={(alert) => console.log(alert)} notificationsArray={[ 'notification1', 'notification2' ]} AddNotification={() => {}} />
}
```

Or, if you want to use it as connected, do

```
// Some third file
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.js'  // Note, that now it is default import

export const AnotherComponent = () => {
  return <MyComponent />
```

Now notice, that I don't provide any props to `MyComponent` a they will be provided by `connect`.

You can also move call to `connect` to some other file. So `MyComponent` will be completely independent of Redux.

You're also not obligated to fully connect `MyCompoent` to Redux. You can partially connect it

```
export default connect (state => ({ alertState: state.alert.alertState }), Alerts.actionCreators)(MyComponent)
```

Now you should provide `notifications` and `AddNotification` when invoking `MyComponent` as they are not taken from Redux.

Comment: Yes, the `connect` HOC is definitely a nice way of decoupling, thank you for pointing that out. I wish there was still a way to invert the dependencies. If I now switch around my `Notification` module with another module that doesn't use redux, then I'd have to go and change all modules that used these exported actionCreators. I'm looking for a way where I can plug in a new `Notification` module, as long as it adheres to some public API (that is preferably not tied directly to redux)

Comment: There also is no `connect` function for a redux saga for example. So it would be more decoupled if in my `Calculations` saga I could call an `addNotification` function from my `Notifications` module, rather than having to use the `put` effect on the action. Because again, this just puts `Notification` action creators all over my code base, and couples the `Notification` module implicitly to the redux library.

Comment: @sjbuysse connect is good but I'm not sure how it helps you decouple your state implementation from redux. Its second argument is `mapDispatchToProps` so you are still tied down to dispatching actions to change your state

Answer (score 1):

I think the idiomatic Redux way *is* for the `Calculation` module to dispatch an action, and modules interested in that action to handle the action in their reducers. Since all actions are passed to all reducers, this makes for less tight coupling between action dispatcher and action consumer. In this case, the `Calculation` module doesn't need to care about which components, how many components, or indeed if any components are watching for that action. (Although in most cases, I find that I do create an action producer and one consumer -- and in most cases just one consumer -- of that action, and even though they are loosely coupled, I work on both at the same time.)

I suppose in theory it is possible to create a `Notification` singleton that you can call from the `Calculation` module, that would in turn dispatch an action that is handled only by the `Notification` module itself. I'm not too familiar with how Angular works, but it seems that if you are calling a function exposed by `Notification`, that creates tight coupling between the components. If you later want to switch out that `Notification` component for another, would you have to see up all the binding again? And what if other components are interested in the `Calculation` success? Does the `Calculation` module have to call functions exposed from singletons in those modules too, introducing more tight coupling?

As with most things, it seems there are pros and cons with both approaches. If you buy into the Redux way of doing things, less tight coupling between components is one of the 'pros', at the expense of less flexiblity should you decide down the road that you want to switch out Redux for a different approach.

Comment: You make a very valid point about having the `Notification` module react to the dispatched actions of my `Calculation` module. But what if you want to make a `Notification` module that you'd like to re-use in other projects?

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking/assuming some things incorrectly.

If you think in a sense, **Actions/reducers etc are organized and written here in a way that makes those particular modules independent**. So, `Notification` here is independent and so is the `Calculation`. Code for both are inside their respective folders. `Calculation` module need not worry of what is happening around the world. `Calculations` related stuffs are done and relevant actions are dispatched or reducers are updated. Now, if some module (e.g. `Notification`) wants to do something when `Calculation` is success, it can listen out for the success dispatch in its own territory.
(Note here that we need not make any changes in the Calculation module for Notification module to work). So, both are decoupled.

`What I find troublesome with that way of working is that you then very tightly couple the module to the redux library` **Yes that is absolutey correct but isn't that what happens when you create a project using some particular framework.** You use the syntaxes and the features provided by those libraries but that makes the overall project tightly bound to that library and if you change the library, a lot of code has to be re-written as per the new library or guidelines (unless there is some intelligent compiler). But, this doesn't makes modules coupled (here in redux at least)

`This means that when I want to replace my Notification module with another Notification module that doesn't use redux, I'll have to refactor my whole app to not use the dispatch function anymore to create a success`. **Yes you have to because underlying library has changed**. *I am not an expert in angular* but even in your angular project, if you decide to use something else for the `Notification` module, I am sure you have to rewrite a lot of stuff in or around the `Calculation` module for things to work out.

I think what you are saying generally happens `if there are very big projects written badly which led to origin of micro-services like architecture`. Take some example of e-commerce website. Initially, Authentication, Search, Checkout, Payment (basically backend services) etc were written altogether and so they were tightly coupled. Later on people created micro-services out of them and each of them can communicate with one another using APIs. Now, each of the service and underlying framework can be changed without effecting other but standard APIs are there. *Similarly, in frontend as well, you can have such things but it essentially means that you have separate projects altogether which need to communicate and not the modules inside the same project. But it will have same issues be in Redux or in Angular.*

**Edit:** Have updated few points after discussion in comments:

#### Can you have micro-frontends

`Yes, you can have micro-frontends` such as `Notifications in` ReactJs`and`Calculations in AngularJs `and use some public methods such as [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or eventListeners but there will be pros and cons to it

Few articles which I found:

- [Frontend in Microservice Architecture](https://medium.com/@vivekmadurai/frontend-in-microservice-architecture-1e5bfa08e3e4)
- [Micro frontends—a microservice approach to front-end web development](https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16)
- https://micro-frontends.org/

#### Is it popular right now?

**No**.
I think some of the reasons being:

- Compared to backend, `frontend is more of UI/UX and has to look consistent in look and feel wise. So, achieving that might be a bit of issue`
- Network latency is a big issue and a lot needs to be downloaded. Using 2 or 3 frameworks means you have to download additional data for that framework to work. E.g. both React and Angular library etc. **If you see, a lot work goes on reducing the download size which will increase upon increasing the number of frameworks**
- Most of the websites don't have many pages. Say at max 10-12 different pages and so, creating all of them in one framework is easy and cheap. However, if the project gets big, then big companies do divide. There are very big projects where a.domain.com is in reactJs, b.domain.com is in angular. But that generally happens when projects are big and completely separated from one another.

**So, yes you can have it but it depends a lot on factors including but not limited to resources, price, availability etc**

#### If you want to build the micro-frontend, you can use

- [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)
- Isolating micro-apps into IFrames using libraries and window.postMessage APIs to coordinate. IFrames share APIs exposed by their parent window
- Event Emitters (a very good library for the same is - https://github.com/chrisdavies/eev)
- Using html5 storage and listening to them for the changes *(on in general anything which lets us to play in or around dom/window because that will be the API layer to help us communicate between different modules)*

Hope, I am able to clarify if for you. Revert for any doubts/confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sunil, as you point out I'm looking for a `micro-service` kind of way of setting up these modules. When you do that, then you can plug and play another `Notification` Module, as long as it adheres to the public facing API. There would be no need to touch any other module like `Calculation`. With exposing action creators in this public facing API this is also possible, but then the new `Notification` module also will have to to expose action creators, which is tied to the redux technology.

Comment: But don't you think unless your Notification and Calculation module are very very big, creating micro-services like architecture is overkill. As you commented in @Bernard's post, if re-usability is the concern, so we make libraries or npm packages; say lodash. Also, there are public APIs/methods like [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or `eventListeners` which can be used as a standard way of communication if say Notification is build in react and Calculcation in Angular. But I am not sure how efficient they are or how much scalable they

Comment: Re-usability is a concern for sure, that's why I use a `Notification` module as an example, since there is a high change I'd like to use module in most of my (hobby) projects. I've never made a react library, but I can imagine that this idea only strengthens my concern since I wouldn't want my library to expose action creators. I'd rather want my `Notification` library to expose an `addNotification` function, right?

Comment: Yes, you can. But currently `there are more cons to it than pros` (have updated few in the answer). `I'd ... Notification ... an addNotification function, right?` No. The reason being, everything is downloaded to user's browser. Even if you expose only `addNotification`, the whole library is there and anyone can download it and understand it. Plus even if whole module is exposed, user's action will effect him or his browser locally only (provided backend is strong). However, if backend is exposed, whole server is exposed which risks others as well so, that logic is apt for backend mainly

Comment: Thank you for this discussion @Sunil, I'm not trying to make micro-frontends. I'm just trying to create a module that is as loosely coupled as possible, having it expose action creators feels like a code smell. More concrete, it feels like a violation of the D in the SOLID principles. I think that's what I'm after, a way to do better dependency inversion in idiomatic react. I think this principle is crucial when it comes to avoiding spaghetti code, even if you don't make separate libraries, micro-frontends and whatnot.

Comment: I agree with you and understood you completely. Even I am searching and getting to know in details few things and updating you the possibilities in which this goal can be achieved. The thing is tuff (maybe the approach is not widely followed or implemented in frontend because effort to result ratio might not be that good)

Answer (score 1):

To decouple a state-module from the Redux dispatch/action paradigm, you can expose a "public API" via hooks:

For example, suppose your module has an action:

```js
// notifications/actions.js
const createNotification = (data) => ({
  type: 'CREATE_NOTIFICATION',
  data
});

// ...
```

In your module, define a hook that returns a function that dispatches the action:

```js
// notifications/hooks.js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { createNotification } from './actions';

function useCreateNotification() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (data) => dispatch(createNotification(data))
}

// ...
```

Now your component doesn't have to know about dispatch/actions. Just import and use the hooks.

```js
// components/MyComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import { useCreateNotification } from './notifications/hooks'

function MyComponent() {
  const createNotification = useCreateNotification();
  const handleClick = () => createNotification('foo');
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Create Notification</button>
  );
}
```

If you need the public API to expose plain (non-hook) functions, you can do this via a higher-order-function that 
takes `dispatch` and returns a set of functions. For the sake of this example, these functions will be termed "endpoints".

```js
// endpoints.js
import * as actions from './actions';

const createEndpoints = (dispatch) => {
  const createNotification = (data) => {
    dispatch(actions.createNotification(data))
  }

  // ...

  return {
    createNotification,
    // ...
  }
}
```

Call the higher-order-function by giving it dispatch:

```js
// store.js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducer';
import { createEndpoints } from './notifications/endpoints';

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, {});

export const { 
  createNotification,
  // ...
} = createEndpoints(store.dispatch);
```

Now your UI doesn't have to know about dispatch, actions, or hooks; just call the plain functions as such:

```js
// MyComponent.js
import { createNotification } from './store'

function MyComponent() {
  const handleClick = () => createNotification('foo');

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Create Notification</button>
  );
}
```

With this approach, you are largely decoupled from a redux implementation. You will still rely on having a redux "dispatch" in order to use the module, but now you are coupled at one point (createEndpoints) instead of many points throughout your components.